# Adding attachments to an email generated in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to create a PS script that does the following:

- Run 2 programs located on the server
- Check for error files
- Attach the error files to the email
- Wait for 5 minutes, rinse and repeat

I've got the below so far, I can get it working **without** the attachments, it just sends a link in the email. However I'd rather they be attachments.

Currently the error I'm getting is "Powershell.exe : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '$null'.".

But I've no idea why this is being generated?

Any advice would be appreciated.

```
#Hide powershell
Powershell.exe -windowstyle hidden {

#Make sure the program isn't running before starting the script 
stop-process -Name WorksOrderCompletionImport
stop-process -Name WorksOrderIssuesImport

#Loop condition
While ($true)
{
$i++

#Bind location to string
$files=Get-ChildItem "E:\Production Siemens Interface Files\error"

#Binding the path to the string
$filechecker = 'E:\Production Siemens Interface Files\error\*.csv'

# Sender and Recipient Info for email
$MailFrom = "myemail@domain.com"
$MailTo = "myemail@domain.com"

# Sender Credentials
$Username = "myemail@domain.com"
$Password = "BadBoiPassword"

# Server Info
$SmtpServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$SmtpPort = "587"

# Message content
$Link = "\\SERVER1\E Drive\Production Siemens Interface Files\error"
$MessageSubject = "Errors have been generated in the Production Siemens Interface Files Folder" 
$Message = New-Object System.Net.Mail.MailMessage $MailFrom,$MailTo
$Message.IsBodyHTML = $true
$Message.Subject = $MessageSubject
$Message.Body = @'
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Hello,</p>
<p>Please be advised that errors have been generated in the Siemens Integration Production Folder.</p>
<p>Please follow this link to check : <a href="\\SERVER1\e$\Production Siemens Interface Files\error">Link to error files</a></p>
</body>
</html>
'@

#Start the programs
start-process -filepath "C:\Program Files\Datel Computing\Siemens Integration PRODUCTION\WorksOrderIssuesImport.exe"
start-process -filepath "C:\Program Files\Datel Computing\Siemens Integration PRODUCTION\WorksOrderCompletionImport.exe"
Start-Sleep -s 10

#If statement to control email
if (Test-Path $filechecker)

# Construct the SMTP client object, credentials, and send
{$Smtp = New-Object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SmtpServer,$SmtpPort)
$Smtp.EnableSsl = $true
$Smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username,$Password)

$attachment = New-Object System.Net.Mail.Attachment –ArgumentList 'E:\Production Siemens Interface Files\error\'$file
$smtp.Attachments.Add($attachment)

$Smtp.Send($Message)}

else { Start-Sleep -s 10
}

#Stop the program
stop-process -Name WorksOrderCompletionImport
stop-process -Name WorksOrderIssuesImport

# Sleep for 300 seconds then loop back
Start-Sleep -s 300

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a lot .net references. I think you can simplify this by using the existing cmdlet Send-MailMessage. For example:

```
$PSEmailServer = "smtp.office365.com"
$smtpPort = "587"
$mailFrom = "myemail@domain.com"
$mailTo = "myemail@domain.com"
$messageSubject = "Errors have been generated in the Production Siemens Interface Files Folder"
$attachment = "E:\Production Siemens Interface Files\error\$file"
$body = @'
<p>Hello,</p>
<p>Please be advised that errors have been generated in the Siemens Integration Production Folder.</p>
<p>Please follow this link to check : <a href="\\SERVER1\e$\Production Siemens Interface Files\error">Link to error files</a></p>
'@

Send-MailMessage -From $mailFrom -To $mailTo -Subject $messageSubject -Body $body -BodyAsHtml -Attachments $attachment -Port $smtpPort -UseSsl
```

See also: [MS Reference Send-MailMessage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/send-mailmessage?view=powershell-5.1#parameters)

Comment: Hi @Mike thanks a lot for your help, however when I run your code I get "A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '587'." - Is it in regards to to the smtp port binding?

Comment: @dylanwb93 That's because `Port` needs to be `-Port`

Comment: Hi Mike, That is amazing thank you! However I am now getting an SMTP authentication failed error message. I believe this is because I am not supplying my credentials for o365 to send the message.

Could you please advise how I would build them into the Send-MailMesage?

Comment: Thank you AdminOfThings. I was in a hurry so i wrote it very fast :-) . I've edited the code

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse you need to supply your credentials for authentication. If you look at the documentation you'll see `-Credential` is one of the parameters. What you can do is:

```
# Define your Credentials
$username = 'your username'
$password= 'your password'

# Crete a credential Object
[SecureString]$secureString = $password | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force 
[PSCredential]$credentialObject = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username, $password
```

Add the `-Credential` parameter to the Send-Mailmessage command like `-Credential $credentialObject`

This is just to show you a way to accomplish what you want, but be careful with this method, because this way you store your password directly in the Script. There are solutions to encrypt your password in external files. You can find a good explanation on: https://pscustomobject.github.io/powershell/howto/Store-Credentials-in-PowerShell-Script/

Comment: Amazing @Mike! Thank you for your help with this!